# Telerik Kendo UI Editor Tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

I understand that Kendo Editor doesn't have full support for tables at the moment. However, I'm needing to allow users to create custom tables with their own column widths and background or border colors. I really don't want to have to support two WYSIWYG editors in my application. Alternatives like TinyMCE have lots of functionality but it's look and feel will be drastically different for my users and it's just yet another component to have to keep up to date.

I'm wondering if there are any plugins made for Kendo Editor that allows for this functionality. I've searched google for something but turned up nil.

One possible solution I've come up with and would appreciate some feedback on is to create some canned table layouts in html and insert the strings into the editor window from a custom button. It still lacks a lot of freedom for user but it gives them something.